# error occured after tableView.endUpdates()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I tried to put a breakpoint and I noticed that error occured after the tableView.endUpdates

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (333) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (333), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   235 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
var myIndex = 0
class TCB_View: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate{

    var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var filteredArray:[String] = []
    var branchesArray:[String] = []
    var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    var isSearchin = false
    deinit {
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
        notificationToken?.invalidate()
    }
    var count = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView?.delegate = self
        tableView?.dataSource = self
        searchBar?.delegate = self
        searchBar?.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        searchBar?.placeholder = "Search Trial Courts"

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self).filter("tc.tc_filter == true")
        count = tcb.count
        print(count)
        for branch in tcb{
                branchesArray.append(branch.branch_name)

        }
        notificationToken = tcb.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
                tableView.reloadData()
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                let fromRow = {(row: Int) in return IndexPath(row: row,section:0) }
                // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map(fromRow),with: .automatic)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map(fromRow),with: .automatic)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map(fromRow),with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            case .error(let error):
                // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == ""{
            isSearchin = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            isSearchin = true
            compositeDisposable.insert(UISearchBar.rx.init(searchBar).value.subscribe(onNext: { (stringResult) in
                self.filteredArray = self.branchesArray.filter({(branchesArray:String) -> Bool in
                    if branchesArray.contains(self.searchBar.text!){
                        return true
                    }else{
                        return false
                    }
                })
            }, onError: { (errorResult) in
                print(errorResult)
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("onCompleted")
            }, onDisposed: {
                print("onDisposed")
            }))
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrialCourtCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
            cell.branchName.text = branchesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

When I tapped the tableCell in my other viewcontroller , error execute

Comment: `count` is not updated while you updating the rows?

Comment: how to update the count sir??

Comment: It's not really clear why when you tapped a cell, this error would happen. But from your error message, since your `numberOfRowsInSection` always return `count`, then in your `.update` you probably need to debug whether `count` is still correct. If not, probably do something like `count = count + insertions.count - deletions.count`

Comment: i have some sort of changing of data, I have a checkmark in my tableViewCell and I want to change the data in my realm database, like changing true(checked) to false(uncheck).

Comment: Ok. Looks like how you handle/fire up this request is not in the question. If the request handling comes back in `case .update(`, then do what I suggested before to debug.

Comment: I already managed to change(change true to false or false to true) the data in realm database then , `notificationToken` `.observe` will reload the `TCB_View class` when detect some changes in realm database and after that the error occur.

Comment: After that or during that? According to your question, it happens at `tableView.endUpdates()`. Please debug around `count` `insertions.count` and `deletions.count` for your `numberOfRowsInSection` to work.

Comment: after detecting some changes the `notificationsToken` execute and get error  at `tableView.endUpdates()` base on the breakpoint. Okay sir I will try to debug and check for the count tomorrow in the office. I can't do it right now because i'm at home.

Comment: its actually working,, `count`-`newCount`(newcount = deletions.count) ,, but the problem is when I delete more the error show up again.. I think I need a condition in my numberOfRowInSection

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` {

        **if (notificationToken != nil)** {
            _return count!-newCount_
        }                                                                                                          
        **else if count!-newCount == 0** {
            _return 0_
        }
        _return count!_
    }

Comment: **I tried this** `self?.count = (self?.count)!+insertions.count-deletions.count` no error found but gives me wrong data

Comment: Don't know what do you mean by wrong data. But the problem defiantly happens with your `count`. You can keep `count `in your `numberOfRowsInSection`, as long as every time you update the data, update the `count` as well.

Comment: the given data is not the right data that I was expecting to show in the tableView, the count is already stable since I add this line `self?.count = (self?.count)!+insertions.count-deletions.count`  but if you tried to analyze the `self?.count = (self?.count)!+insertions.count-deletions.count` it's only determine the count which is the number of row. It doesn't have any relation to the data fetch from database.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer related to this specific question. You will need to analyse what else is wrong.

Comment: **Example**  `Array["A","B","C","D","E"]` in the tableView displays `TABLE : A,B,C,D,E` (I dont know how to do new line here I hope you understand), then when I delete `"A","D"` the tableView show `TABLE : A,B,C` , so basically the line  `self?.count = (self?.count)!+insertions.count-deletions.count` is just added and delete count of rows.

Comment: yeah you are right sorry,,, thanks for the help by the way. I just did another solution not recommendable way. I'll get back to this problem soon. I have something to finish asap